# How to use socket.io with node.js worker_threads

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, node-worker-threads

Currently I am introducing `worker_threads` to a game I am developing. Thea idea is to have each game room in a separate thread, so that they can be processed in parallel (yeah I know that will only really happen if there isn't more threads than cores).

However, I cannot get `socket.io` to work with `worker_threads`. So far I have tried the following:

**1. Create the `socket.io` server within the server:**

*server.js*

```
const { Worker, isMainThread } = require("worker_threads");

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.post("/newGame", (request, response) => {
  let roomCode = request.query.room_code;
  const worker = new Worker("./server-worker.js", {
    workerData: {
      roomCode: roomCode
    },
  });
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.info("Server started on http://localhost:8080");
});
```

*server-worker.js*

```
const { parentPort, workerData, threadId } = require("worker_threads");


const server = require("http").createServer();
const io = require("socket.io")(server);

server.listen(8080, () => {
  console.info("Server socket.io on port 8080");
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(`Client with ID ${socket.id} connected to thread with ID ${threadID}`);
});
```

This results in the browser logging this:
`GET http://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t= 404 (Not Found)`

Also even if I got Express to forward the polling request to the worker I am guessing that I would not be able to open more than one room since the port would already be in use.

**2. Create `socket.io` instance in main thread and pass it on**

*server.js*

```
const { Worker, isMainThread } = require("worker_threads");

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server);

app.post("/newGame", (request, response) => {
  let roomCode = request.query.room_code;
  const worker = new Worker("./server-worker.js", {
    workerData: {
      roomCode: roomCode,
      io: io
    },
  });
});
```

However, this does not work since I get a `DataCloneError` because worker_threads can only send native objects to workers.

**Questions:**

- Is there an easier way to accomplish what I am doing? I.e.: Am I just using the wrong framworks?
- Is there a way to get `socket.io` working with threads? I already saw a documentation on using it with node.js clusters using a Redis instance but that seems overkill for the problem at hand since I do not have multiple processes/ nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node's worker threads are not suitable for your purpose. They're for doing long-running computations, not handling network connections.

Also, it probably does not make sense to assign your rooms to particular server resources. Node is good at concurrently handling multiple app contexts and so is socket.io.

To scale up your app to use more processor cores, node offers clustering. To use a cluster you'll need to sort out session stickiness.

Comment: Thanks! I am completely new to both JavaScript and game dev so this input is very valuable. I had the impression this was a good idea from another post here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/379272/multithreading-thread-per-area-for-an-mmo-server-good-idea

Comment: If you were writing your code in C# / dotnet / unity, threads would be a reasonable choice for you: in that language, runtime, and tool chain threads can do both IO and computing concurrently, and they're much cheaper to create than they are in dotnet. But you would still be wise to assign your threads to connected users, not to game rooms. The C# APIs for socket.io naturally fit work with a thread per connection.  Using async/ await you can, and should, emulate that in node. But you won't be using real threads, instead node-style asynchronous programming.